# How to add an Environ Variable Path to VS command Prompt

Tags: c#, command-line, visual-studio-2012

If I open `Developer Command Prompt for VS2012` using 'Run as Administrator' and then run the following will the path `C:\foo` get added to the list of environment variable pathways for the command prompt? (or will all the existing pathways get replaced by `C:\foo`?)

`setx path "%path%;C:\foo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command
path "%path%;C:\foo"

documented help for path
PATH /?
Displays or sets a search path for executable files.
PATH [[drive:]path[;...][;%PATH%]
PATH ;

Type PATH ; to clear all search-path settings and direct cmd.exe to search only in the current directory.
Type PATH without parameters to display the current path.

Including %PATH% in the new path setting causes the old path to be appended to the new setting.